# How can I turn my cavas item into a traditional image?

Tags: javascript, python, html, canvas

I am essentially trying to turn my canvas drawing into a "something.png" for upload to s3 via heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python Based off of the steps in this link,
[This is how the image to be uploaded looks like in console.log() before it is to be uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXHo.png).

```
File {name: 'cat2.png', lastMOdified:16666, lastmodifiedDate: Sun sep 25 2022}, webkitrelativepath: '', size:17131, ..}
    lastmodified:166666
    >lastModifiedDate: Sun sep 25 2022
    name: 'cat2.png'
    size: 171323
    type: 'image/png'
    webkitrelativepath: ""
    >[[prototype]]: File
```

It's simply an image.png that is selected from the users computer. In my situation I have a canvas I want to convert into a something.png for upload as well, but I can't convert it into something that looks like the image above. The code im running looks as follows :

```
    function tester(){
        var tester = canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log("what you will see below is canvas.todataurl");
        console.log(tester);
        var nowblob = dataURItoBlob(tester);
        console.log("--------------");
        console.log(nowblob);
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("namestring", nowblob);
        console.log(fd);
    }
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var array = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
    }
```

But again, I cannot convert it into [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqXHo.png). The closest I've gotten is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgGrm.png).

```
what you will see below is canvas.todataurl
data:image/png;base64, ivBORw0K........
------
Blob 
    size : 3995
    type : 'image/jpeg'
    [[prototype]] : blob
-------
FormData 
    [[prototype]] : FormData
```

When it is a blob it looks almost in the form of what I need but not exactly. I don't have a great understanding of javascript objects and datastructures so am really struggling here. Please advise / help if you have any idea yourself! Thanks so much everyone

Comment: [Don't show pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Put the text in your post. Also, properly indent your code, so people can easily read it. Remember, you're asking real people for help, you are expected to follow the posting guidelines.

Comment: for sure let me fix everything sorry about that

Comment: note: _either_ four spaces, or code fences, but not both =D Also, your "what I want" and "this" links should still not be links. Those are normal text, put them in your post as text (either quoted or formatted as code. Since it's console output, probably the latter).

Comment: If you already have a `Blob`, can't you just do a `new File([blob], "image.png")`?

Comment: arckoor, that is exactly what i was looking for. THat turned my blob into the form that i wanted it and i got it to work , thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `Blob` instantly with the [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method. All you need to do then, is pass the `Blob` into a new [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). A `File` interface is basically just a `Blob` with some extra properties, like a `name`.

```
async function getImageFromCanvas(canvas, name) {
  const blob = await new Promise(resolve => {
    canvas.toBlob(resolve, 'image/png');
  });

  const file = new File([blob], name);
  return file;
}
```

```
getImageFromCanvas(canvas, 'something.png')
  .then(file => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('something', file);
  });
```